# Prove that a real-valued differential function is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For example, where $C^1[a,b]$ is the vector space of a real-valued differential function (RVDF),

$L:C^1[1,2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}; L(f)=3\int_1^2f(x)dx $

or

$L:C^1[1,7] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; L(f) = f(5)+2f(3)-f(1)$

What does $f$ represent? Is it any arbitrary RVDF?

Comment: Actually, you should check your definitions. $C^1$ is the space of *continuously differentiable* functions. But, of course, when you write $L(f)$, $f$ is in the domain of $L$, which here is $C^1[1,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, $f$ is an element of the domain. In this case, it is an element of $C^1[a,b]$.

---

More generally, a transformation $T:D\to F$ over $K$  is linear if it satisfies the two conditions:

1. For any $f, g\in D$, then $T(f+g)=T(f)+T(g)$;
2. For any $f\in D$, $c\in K$, then $T(cf)=cT(f)$.

By way of getting you started, I will demonstrate on the transformation $T(f)=\dfrac{df}{dx}+f(0)$, where $f\in C^1[-1,1]$ over $\mathbb{R}. I will check each condition in turn.

Condition 1. Given, $f, g\in C^1[-1,1]$,
$$\begin{align}
T(f+g)&=\frac{d(f+g)}{dx}+(f+g)(0)\\
&=\frac{df}{dx}+\frac{dg}{dx}+f(0)+g(0)\\
&=\frac{df}{dx}+f(0)+\frac{dg}{dx}+g(0)\\
&=T(f)+T(g).
\end{align}$$

Condition 2. Given $f\in C^1[-1,1]$, $c\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\begin{align}
T(cf)&=\frac{d(cf)}{dx}+(cf)(0)\\
&=c\frac{df}{dx}+cf(0)\\
&=c\left(\frac{df}{dx}+f(0)\right)\\
&=cT(f)
\end{align}$$

Hence, since both conditions are satisfied, the transformation $T$ is linear.

---

You need to show that for both of your transformations, the two conditions above are satisfied.